# Issue customizing my .htaccess file to for SEO purposes

Tags: .htaccess

I've successfully used this method:

```
RewriteEngine On
## SEO REWRITE

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.atlantalawvideo.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.atlantalawvideo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to make `www.atlantalawvideo.legalvideoconsulting.com` forward to `www.atlantalawvideo.com`.

I can't get this method to work with my `.org` and `.net` add `.on` domains. I'm using bluehost if that is relevant.

Thanks

Comment: What are you your `.org OR .net` domains? Are they pointed to same host and same DocumentRoot?

Comment: They are www.legalvideographer.org and legalvideographer.net - They are in the same document root I believe. One is in a folder labeled "legalvideorapher" and the other is "howtobecomea"- Do the folder names have to match the domain names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place same rule in these 2 locations also:

1. `/legalvideorapher/.htaccess`
2. `/howtobecomea/.htaccess`

Make sure you have rule like this with more correct regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.([^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I do have unique .htaccess files in those respective folders. I will try your regex code.

Comment: Yes understood but you need to create them in order to redirect those 2 additional sites as well.

Comment: Here is the code I have in the /legalvideographer/ folder in its .htaccess file:                                          RewriteEngine On
## SEO REWRITE

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.legalvideographer.org
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.legalvideographer.org/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I'm now using your regex code on legalvideographer.org:  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.legalvideographer\.org$ [NC
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.legalvideographer.org/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

Comment: I think I am. Is the .org as opposed to .com the issue?

Comment: Yes it is because you want to redirect all the sites to `http://www.atlantalawvideo.com/`

Comment: Actually no. I'm trying to get all my various sites to appear as primary domains to the search engines. I'm attempting to forward the secondary.primary.com sites to just www.secondary.com.

Comment: I tried using:                                               RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.legalvideographer.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.org/$1 [R=301,L,NE]                                                          Still getting server error...

Comment: Try updated rule again and don't include `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.legalvideographer.org [NC]` condition.